# Where is the new Airport in Need For Speed: World?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

I heard there is a new airport in the recently unlocked areas of the Need For Speed: World.

Where is it?

Comment: I'm putting this here because _many_ people asked about this today on the game chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Screenshot.]

The new airport has been added to the easternmost section of the Rockport highway. A section has been added to each ring; the upper one is pictured, the lower one is a bus hub.